# Cabal Vs runhaskell, when to use?

Tags: haskell, cabal

In haskell build system, `Cabal` as well as `runhaskell` has got almost same set of sub-commands, `configure`, `build`. For runhaskell, it is:

```
runhaskell Setup.hs configure
runhaskell Setup.hs build
```

...whereas for cabal it is:

```
cabal build
cabal configure
```

So, when should I use which command? Do both the commands have same functionality?

Can I run `runhaskell` without sudo access, because I see `runhaskell` makes entries inside `/opt/ghc/7.8.4/lib` whereas cabal works in sudo/non-sudo mode?

Comment: When do you see `runhaskell` creating entries under `/opt/ghc/7.8.4/lib` ?

Comment: sorry folks, i saw in this link http://bob.ippoli.to/archives/2013/01/11/getting-started-with-haskell/, two commands being used... runhaskell Setup.hs configure && runhaskell Setup.hs build... that put me in a soup...

Comment: i see entries in /opt/ghc/7.8.4 when i gave the wrong cmd - `runhaskell Setup.hs install`... now i am clear, i can't use install with `runhaskell`

Comment: It's highly likely that it's command line arguments being passed. See the source here: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.2/docs/html/libraries/Cabal-1.10.1.0/src/Distribution-Simple.html#defaultMain

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cabal` and `runhaskell` serve entirely different purpose.
        `runhaskell` is used for executing Haskell programs without
        having the need to compile them. You can place this on the top of an Haskell file: `#!/usr/bin/env runhaskell` and give it the scripting ability. The `cabal` is a package manager and a build system
        for Haskell.

Also `cabal` and `runhaskell` don't share their sub-commands like
     `configure`, `build`, `install` etc.

---

> i saw in this link bob.ippoli.to/archives/2013/01/11/getting-started-with-haskell, two commands being used... runhaskell Setup.hs configure && runhaskell Setup.hs build

Usually `Setup.hs` has the following code when generated from `cabal init`:

```
import Distribution.Simple
main = defaultMain
```

Now if you see the implementation of [defaultMain](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.2/docs/html/libraries/Cabal-1.10.1.0/src/Distribution-Simple.html#defaultMain):

```
defaultMain :: IO ()
defaultMain = getArgs >>= defaultMainHelper simpleUserHooks
```

So what you are passing is actually command line arguments which can be anything. In fact you can test that yourself:

```
$ runhaskell Setup.hs invalid_argument
unrecognised command: invalid_argument (try --help)
```

Answer (score 2):

`runhaskell` doesn’t have any subcommands:

> $ runhaskell --help
>   Usage: runghc [runghc flags] [GHC flags] module [program args]

It takes a path to a Haskell source file and executes it right away. So you should use it when all you want is to run some Haskell code you have. Of course, you can use `runhaskell` without superuser access; I doubt it creates anything in `/opt`.

Cabal is a build-system for Haskell projects, its purpose is transforming Haskell sources into binaries.